# Clone labels, input boxes together in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I've got the following HTML inside the tag "#valgmulighed1" that i want to clone in jquery when the user presses a button. I want my jquery to append a class, so that the user can delete the individual rows added. I guess some sort of loop will be neccesary in order to give each of the cloned content an "unique" class, so that the script doesnt delete all of the rows.

My HTML is here:

```
<input type="button" id="btnid" value="+" />
<div id="valgmulighed1">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="sv1" />
        <span class="label-text">Rigtigt</span>
    </label>
    <input id="Text3" type="text" class="spmtekst2" placeholder="Tekst valgmulighed" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Tekst valgmulighed'" />
    <div class="slet">
        <span>Slet</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do a jquery script on this, without the loop, just to first and foremost see if i can get the clone function right.

```
$("btnid").click(function () {
    $('#valgmulighed1').clone().attr('id', 'id_' + $('#valgmulighed1').index()).inserAfter('#valgmulighed1');
})
```

However it doesnt, so i kinda need some help at this point.

Comment: `inserAfter` ??  typo mistake? it should `insertAfter`

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selector is wrong. It should `#btnid` instead of `btnid`. Instead of generating unique `id` it is better to use class. Here I use `valgmulighed` class. On click of `.slet` remove closest `.valgmulighed` like following.

```js
$("#btnid").click(function () {
    $('.valgmulighed:last').clone().attr('id', 'valgmulighed' + ($('.valgmulighed').length + 1)).insertAfter('.valgmulighed:last');
});

$('body').on('click', '.slet', function () {
    if ($('.slet').length > 1)
        $(this).closest('.valgmulighed').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnid" value="+" />
<div class="valgmulighed" id="valgmulighed1">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="sv1" />
        <span class="label-text">Rigtigt</span>
    </label>
    <input id="Text3" type="text" class="spmtekst2" placeholder="Tekst valgmulighed" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Tekst valgmulighed'" />
    <div class="slet">
        <span>Slet</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i wrote a slobby code, im sorry for taking your time! 
However, could i make a while loop to give unique id's with the increment? and how would i go around deleting the individual rows after?

Comment: thats great! but what if i wanted each of them to be like: 
valgmulighed1 
valgmulighed2
valgmulighed3 
etc. etc. 

The purpose of this, is to insert into a database. They should emerge in the same order when it is pulled back from the database.

Comment: OK. Then use `id` and `class` both. See updated answer. @JeppeC

Comment: Anyway, it is possible for me to delete some of the blocks, and end up with the same id in two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error `inserAfter` should be `insertAfter` and has wrong selector it should `$("#btnid")`. You should use `class` then `id`. On deleting row you have to use  delete button click event `$(this).parents("valgmulighed:first").remove();`

```js
$("#btnid").click(function () {
     $('.valgmulighed:last').clone().insertAfter('.valgmulighed:last');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnid" value="+" />
<div class="valgmulighed">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="sv1" />
        <span class="label-text">Rigtigt</span>
    </label>
    <input id="Text3" type="text" class="spmtekst2" placeholder="Tekst valgmulighed" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Tekst valgmulighed'" />
    <div class="slet">
        <span>Slet</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JeppeC you should check in marked answer `inserAfter` not changed. should i get my credits?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in button selector 
put an `#` on your jquery button selector $("**#btnid**").click(...

this is a common mistake, happens a lot with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnid").click(function() {
    $('#valgmulighed1').clone().attr('id', 'id_' +  $('div[id*="id_"]').length).insertAfter('#valgmulighed1');
})
```

You've used $('#valgmulighed1').index(), but it is not correct. Every time you call that code, you'll get the same result, because there is only one that kind of element, so your elements created will have same id.